# Highlight a part of string which has html entities as text : angularJs

Tags: html, angularjs, highlighting

I have :

```
$scope.text = "<b>TESTNAME</b>"; (This can be any string. This is to specify that there can be html tags written as text in the string.)
```

The bold tags are part of text and need to be displayed as text only and not HTML.

Now suppose someone enters a search string(for eg.. anyone can enter any string) :

```
$scope.searchTerm = "NAME";
```

Then i want that $scope.text gets modified such that i see `<b>TESTNAME</b>` but with the substring of "NAME" highlighted.

My highlight function does :

```
$scope.text = $scope.text.replace(new RegExp("(" + $scope.searchTerm + ")","gi"), "<span class='highlighted'>\$1</span>");
```

and in the HTML I had to write :

```
<span ng-bing-html="text"></span>
```

However, the issue now arises is that, the `<b>` and `</b>` also get rendered in the HTML form and bold the string in between.

How can this be handled?

**EDIT**
In order to avoid the b tags from rendering as HTML, I modified the angular brackets to their HTML counterparts using this :

```
$scope.text = $scope.text.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
```

after using the first replace function mentioned above. Now when the $scope.text is rendered using ng-bing-html, the b tags are only rendered as text.
However, now the span tags added are also rendered as text as angular brackets have been replaced globally.

**EDIT**
Another way to deal with the problem was that i replaced the angular tags before adding the span tags to highlight the text. So my highlight function was :

```
  $scope.text = $scope.text.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
    $scope.searchTerm = $scope.searchTerm.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
    $scope.text = $scope.text.replace(new RegExp("(" + $scope.searchTerm + ")","gi"), "<span class='highlighted'>\$1</span>");
```

However, the issue with this is that if the user searches for the string `lt` or `gt`,then due to the replacements done for < and >, the highlight spans are added to these too and the net result is not as expected.

Comment: Change the replace in your edit so that it's specifically matching <b> and </b>, instead of < and >.  .replace(/<b>/g, '&lt;b&gt;').replace(/</b>/g, '&lt;/b&gt;');

Comment: Alternatively, just swap the order of those statements so you escape the <b> tags before adding in the <span>

Comment: @JamesBrierley : it can be any search string which can contain any html tag. Also, swapping the order will not help as mentioned in the second query where the user searches for 'lt' only

Answer (score 0):

Please check working example: [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/TSeb7sUF0KR88yaxA70H?p=preview)

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ["ngSanitize"]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.searchTerm = "NAME";
    $scope.content = "TESTNAME";
    $scope.matchClass = 'bold';
    var re = new RegExp($scope.searchTerm, 'g');
    $scope.content = $scope.content.replace(re, '<span class="' + $scope.matchClass + '">' + $scope.searchTerm + '</span>');
});
```

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <p ng-bind-html="content"></p>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: new solution:

```
$scope.text = $scope.text.replace(new RegExp("(" + $scope.searchTerm + ")","gi"), "long-random-string-one$1long-random-string-two");

// Any encoding goes here

$scope.text = $scope.text.replace("long-random-string-one", "<span class='highlighted'>").replace("long-random-string-two", "</span>")
```

The idea is to insert two strings that won't be changed by the encoding, and are unique enough that they are extremely unlikely to be present in the text you are searching.  Replace them with GUIDs if you want.

Comment: This would have definitely worked but the deal is that the my highlight regex is with "gi" attributes. This means that the regex u provided would not work since the original string is matched case insensitively

Comment: @BhumiSinghal I've edited my answer with a new solution